# how can I use hibernate to get OneToMany reference datas

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to make a OrderMeal web project in using SpringMvc+Spring+hibernate.
But it seens that I got some problems at printing the datas on my jsp pages.

when I debug the project(I'm sorry that I can't post the debug picture  T_T)

I can not figure out that why the property "mealOrders" is always empty...
but i have already insert many datas into the tables.

here are my entitys and HQL query

> User class

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="UserBaseInfo")
public class User implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long userID;//id
    private String userName;
    private String loginname;
    private String userPassword;
    private String cleartextPassword;
    private String postion;
    private String telePhone;
    private String email;
    private String userLocation;
    private Date createTime;
    private Date lastEditTime;
    private Date passwordEditTime;
    private int onlineTime;
    private String lastLoginIP;
    private int loginCount;
    private int userState;

    private Set<MealOrder> mealOrders = new HashSet<MealOrder>();
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }
    ...I hide some useless propertys
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=MealOrder.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<MealOrder> getMealOrders() {
        return mealOrders;
    }

    public void setMealOrders(Set<MealOrder> mealOrders) {
        this.mealOrders = mealOrders;
    }
```

> MealOrder class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MealOrder")
public class MealOrder  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long mealOrderID;
    private int orderState;
    //private Long userID;
    private String userName;
    private String postion;
    private String telePhone;
    private String userLocation;
    private Date orderTime;
    private String restaurantName;
    private int restaurantID;
    private String supplyTimeType;
    private Date beginSupplyTime;
    private Date endSupplyTime;
    private Date beginSupplyDate;
    private Date endSupplyDate;
    private int mealMenuID;
    private String mealMenuName;
    private String mealPackageName;
    private int mealPackageID;
    private float mealPackagePrice;

    private User user;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long getMealOrderID() {
        return mealOrderID;
    }

    public void setMealOrderID(Long mealOrderID) {
        this.mealOrderID = mealOrderID;
    }
    ...I hide some useless propertys
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserID")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

and the HQL query below

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<User> FindAllUsers() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("from User u left join u.mealOrders");
    return (List<User>) query.list();
}
```

and my jsp page(it can not print the datas)

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
            <tr>
                <td>${user.userName}</td>
                <td>${user.userID}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

how can I print the datas on the jsp page?

Comment: you meant you cant print mealOrder s of a User ? Do you get any exception?

Comment: no really any exceptions ,but I don't know how can I write the codes so that the datas can shown on the jsp page.thanks for helping:)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can make the fetch type EAGER which will force User to always retrieve it's children (not desired performance-wise in case you don't always need all the data).
2. You can "get" the children while the transaction is still open which will result in another query to the DB.
3. You can change your query to "left join **fetch**" to force the object creation.

Comment: It works now,the reason is I can't handle "LAZY",thanks for your great help:)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand why you need this query when you already have mapping in place. If you give simple select statement, that may work. Avoid join in the query.

Comment: See that FetchType.LAZY is used, may be he should modify it to Eager if accessed outside the transaction